# Madara/Pain's Rinnegan

Tags: naruto

As we know, Pain has Madara's Rinnegan. The Indra Path of Pain uses a lot of Shinra Tenseis and Bansho Tenins, but I have never seen Madara using any of the above.

Why is this so?

Comment: Maybe Madara didn't see the need to use it. Madara, being the original owner of the eyes, can utilize the Rinnegan to it's full potential, whereas Nagato could just use it.

Comment: Probably.Maybe he thought it was a weak technique.

Answer (score 1):

Madara has shown throughout the battles he fought that he was just toying with the others. At one point, after his rinne rebirth, he even cuts his own body just to relive the pleasure of a real battle. He clearly preferred to have actual combats than just winning the fight, probably because once everybody becomes a zombie under the tsuki no me he would have no one to fight.

Answer (score -1):

I think the techniques that pain had  are new and been invented by him madara was dead till he knew that abilities. Yet, his susanoo is enough to whitewash entire battlefield. And every one has their own signatures.

Comment: All Rinnegan users have access to all Pain's ability